# BlackBerry How to fix footer manager using native API

Tags: blackberry-jde

I have a header , listfield and footer in my application's main page.  I use horizontalfield manager for footer and header.The header is a banner and footer is a tabs container. I add the header, the listfield and the footer to the screen respectively. So I can fix the header but the footer is below the listfield and the wasn't shown in the screen if a listfield have many content.

I think I have to fix footer to the bottom of the device screen.
Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setStatus(footer);